# Can’t Boot Into Linux Anymore - stuck in emergency mode

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, boot-repair

I am running dual boot with Ubuntu and Windows (I had windows first). I recently reset the bios settings to default due to another issue that I was having. I also restored Factory Keys under the secure boot configuration menu. Since then the grub dual boot menu is missing and it boots directly into Windows. By default, the startup bios setting is set to UEFI only. 
I have disabled secure boot and tried to run boot-repair through a live Ubuntu session through a USB. Doing this returns the error “locked NVram” and doesn’t fix the problem. I don’t know what this means and I have tried many other variations and settings, but nothing seems to work. 
My computer is a Thinkpad T490, Ubuntu is 18.04, and Windows 10.

UPDATE:
After trying this command (in Windows), I finally got back the grub boot menu:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

But when I select Ubuntu from the boot menu, it loads very long and then brings me into emergency mode where I have the following options:

```
    You are in emergency mode. 
After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, 
"systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" 
or ^D to try again to boot into default mode".
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Seems the problem has to do with the changed bios settings.  Let us know what you changed and why, so someone can give good information.  Should also give at least computer make and model with which version of Ubuntu and Windows.  Edit your question with this information.  Different hardware and version of OS might need different answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Just added hardware, the bios settings are the default settings except that I disabled secure boot because otherwise boot repair had a different error.

Comment: Maybe the drive has some RAID or RAID-like configuration. [Try AHCI](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/67qdzu/nvme_pcie_ssd_raid_or_ahci_mode_for_linuxubuntu/). Maybe 'secure boot' is enabled. Try to turn it off (somewhere in the UEFI/BIOS menu system).

Answer (score 0):

Go to Firmware settings. In boot sequence move `Ubuntu` above `Windows boot manager`. This will solve your issue.